# AWS DMS keeps on restarting the table import

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am pulling in a large database with some large tables (over 80 million rows) that are on Microsoft SQL Server.

I am experiencing weird behaviour where the table loads start reloading after around 60 minutes (or a few minutes over that). I am doing a full load + cdc and this problem occurs on the full load part.

This is how my setting looks like:

```
     {
        "TargetMetadata": {
            "TargetSchema": "",
            "SupportLobs": true,
            "FullLobMode": false,
            "LobChunkSize": 0,
            "LimitedSizeLobMode": true,
            "LobMaxSize": 102400,
            "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
            "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
            "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
            "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0,
            "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
            "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false
        },
        "FullLoadSettings": {
            "TargetTablePrepMode": "DROP_AND_CREATE",
            "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": true,
            "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
            "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
            "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 16,
            "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
            "CommitRate": 50000
        },
        "Logging": {
            "EnableLogging": true,
            "LogComponents": [
                {
                    "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD",
                    "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
                },
                {
                    "Id": "TARGET_LOAD",
                    "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
                },
                {
                    "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE",
                    "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
                },
                {
                    "Id": "TARGET_APPLY",
                    "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
                },
                {
                    "Id": "TASK_MANAGER",
                    "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
                }
            ]
        },
        "ControlTablesSettings": {
            "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
            "ControlSchema": "",
            "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
            "HistoryTableEnabled": false,
            "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": false,
            "StatusTableEnabled": false
        },
        "StreamBufferSettings": {
            "StreamBufferCount": 3,
            "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8,
            "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5
        },
        "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
            "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
            "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
            "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
        },
        "ErrorBehavior": {
            "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
            "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
            "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
            "DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
            "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
            "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
            "TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
            "RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
            "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
            "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
            "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
            "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
            "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
            "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
            "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
            "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
            "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
            "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
            "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
            "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": false
        },
        "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
            "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
            "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
            "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
            "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
            "BatchSplitSize": 0,
            "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
            "CommitTimeout": 1,
            "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024,
            "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
            "StatementCacheSize": 50
        },
        "PostProcessingRules": null,
        "CharacterSetSettings": null,
        "LoopbackPreventionSettings": null
    }
```

I do not see anything useful in the logs on the Cloudwatch, except that the endpoint is disconnected. More logs below:

```
2022-08-21T13:34:59 [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]E: Endpoint is disconnected [1020414] (endpointshell.c:3807)
2022-08-21T13:34:59 [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]E: Error executing source loop [1020414] (streamcomponent.c:1872)
2022-08-21T13:34:59 [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Stream component failed at subtask 5, component st_5_STAX7TAMIRB2R3PAIOSXO6TO7KT6PPIVMPGYLNQ [1020414] (subtask.c:1414)
2022-08-21T13:34:59 [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]E: Stream component 'st_5_STAX7TAMIRB2R3PAIOSXO6TO7KT6PPIVMPGYLNQ' terminated [1020414] (subtask.c:1594)
2022-08-21T13:34:59 [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Task error notification received from subtask 5, thread 0 [1020414] (replicationtask.c:2880)
2022-08-21T13:34:59 [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Endpoint is disconnected; Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 5, component st_5_STAX7TAMIRB2R3PAIOSXO6TO7KT6PPIVMPGYLNQ; Stream component 'st_5_STAX7TAMIRB2R3PAIOSXO6TO7KT6PPIVMPGYLNQ' terminated [1020414] (replicationtask.c:2888)
```

Also, I noticed that DMS job tries to do this import 10 times and each time it takes around 1 hour to get this message and at the end it ends up in the FAILED stage.

We have tried to increase the timeout on the SQL server side (QueryTimeOut) to 2 hours, but that didn't help.

Can someone advice what else can be done here? Also, I would like for the DMS job not to "retry" for 10 times, since probably 3-4 times would be enough.

Comment: Might be one best for AWS support if you have access to them.

Comment: hey, facing same issue in prod. did you found a solution?

Comment: AWS support adviced to separate problematic tables into separated job. Not really a solution in my opinion, but a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate task for the problematic tables.  Seems to be working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with AWS support the conclusion was that the connection from the source was problematic as some tables that I was loading were huge and they have at the same time a lot of active transaction (inserts). Since I was connecting to the MirrorDB (read replica), the combination of all these mentioned above lead to that that the connection is unstable and mirror db was out-of-sync with the main DB, so it was trying to re-sync which caused DMS to fail on the initial load.

The solution was to create separate DMS jobs per year (just so the initial load is not too big).

This is due to the fact that some tables have 500 million records.